# Hide Views Module Page if Field is Empty

Tags: views, 7

I am using drupal 7 and views 3.x. I am creating a page using views module. Page content came from content type. Example: I've page A which I create using views module. The page content came from field Z, which is one of field from content type X. Then, for the contextual filter, I use author id. So, my question is: how can I hide the page if field Z return null value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried 'no result behavior ??

Comment: When you create a page from views you have to give it a URL, and if you have a URL, you must display something, so I don't understand how you want to 'hide' a page. If you want to display something else, use the no result behaviors mention above. There are two ways to do this, in the contextual filter settings and in the field settings.